# Which Sharepoint authentication method do you use and why?

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, active-directory, kerberos, ntlm

Kerberos, NTLM, forms, claims based, use of active directory?

Going through the difficult process of analyzing which authentication method to use for a Sharepoint build-out, and I must be honest in saying that I'm confused as to which the best use-case would be. It's going to be used as an intranet and extranet, and am wondering what authentication methods other people are using and why they chose the authentication method they did.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We use claims based kerberos.

Claims based because we started with Windows authentication, but want to leave the option for enabling forms based authentication open. (Forms based authentication is not available in classic mode)

Kerberos because it allows us to overcome the double-hop problem.

Setting up Kerberos brings some additional configuration requirements. Although it may seem intimidating at first, it is well documented: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1a794fb5-77d0-475c-8738-ea04d3de1147&displaylang=en

Also claims based authentication has it's problems/limitations, but until now I didn't encounter something that made me change my mind about it.

In your case, if you want to make your SharePoint available as an extranet environment, you may want to go for claims based authentication. That way you can use Windows authentication for internal people and forms authentication for external people (customers/suppliers/...).

Answer (score 0):

When making integrations NTLM is the preferred one, Kerberos is nice (and safer) but if the AD goes down your intranets and extranets wont be accessible.

So, Kerberos if you are paranoid, NTLM if you want high availability and good enough security.